# Datatables - change column width using `columnDefs`

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to adjust the width of specific columns (wrapping long content AND headers) in a table but have not been successful.

Following the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs), I am still not able to adjust the width of specified columns, am I missing something?

I have the following DataTable parameters for a `table` with `id=one` and `width=100%`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#one').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        'scrollX': false,
        'autoWidth': false,
        'columnDefs' : [
            {'targets': [0,1], 'width': '50px'}
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        'lengthMenu': [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel']
    });
});
```

I have not specified any CSS overrides in the HTML or otherwise, so maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure about this one, Nick, but I would try removing the `autoWidth` parameter.  This could be a problem if you haven't specified the width of all of your columns.  I generally don't use `columnDefs` (I use `columns` instead and spell out what I want for each column), and I want DataTables to automatically size any columns for which I don't specify the width.  So I don't use `autoWidth` either.  That's what works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the responses. After some additional digging, I realized the table was being set with the class of nowrap. So annoying. After removing this class, the wrap works as required. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What data are you putting in the column? The width property is only applied to the `th` element, so if there are wider elements in the column `td` cells they might make the column wider than you expect. For example, an image wider than 50px would make the column wider than 50px.

Comment: All data are strings.  Good point on `th` versus `td` updates.  So, is there a way I can update `td`?

Comment: @NickBraunagel I wouldn't.  You want the width for the column, so `th` is cleaner.  And DataTables will always wordwrap strings anyway unless you specify otherwise.  Perhaps your strings don't have spaces, and are wider than will fit in 50px?  I've never tried that before, so I don't know what it will do.  Haven't tried it because I wouldn't want to make the column narrower than would fit my data anyway.  I can't imagine why you might either, but...?

Comment: @NickBraunagel AFAIK you would need to use CSS to target the `td` separate from the `th`. That being said, the cells won't really obey `width` or `max-width` declarations as [table layouts either use fixed or auto width calculations](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout). For the width precision you are looking for, you're almost stuck changing the `display` value of the cells to `inline-block` or something.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses.  After some additional digging, I realized the table was being set with the class of `nowrap`.  So annoying.  After removing this class, the wrap works as required.  Thank you.